# Skip first row and delete certain char before importing csv to db

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I'm new to Python, and my task is to import the csv to mysql database. I have this sample values inside my csv file:

```
SHA1,VSDT,TRX
005c41fc0f8580f51644493fcbaa0d2d468312c3,(WIN32 (EXE 7-2)),Ransom.Win32.TRX.XXPE50FFF027,
006ea7ce2768fa208ec7dfbf948bffda9da09e4e,WIN32 EXE 2-2,TROJ.Win32.TRX.XXPE50FFF027,
```

My problem here is, how can I remove `"( "` and `")"` only at the start and end point of string at the second column before importing to database?

**I have this code to import the csv**

```
import csv
import mysql.connector
file = open(fullPath, 'rb')  
csv_data = csv.reader(file)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
cursor = mydb.cursor()
for row in csv_data:
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO jeremy_table_test(sha1,vsdt,trendx)'
               'VALUES(%s, %s, %s)',[(row[0]),(row[1]),(row[2]))
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
print("Done")
```

Comment: You get the IO error because you transact on f1 after you closed it, i.e., it's outside the indentation of the `with open() as f1` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL `LOAD DATA` tool can probably do what you want here.  Here is what the `LOAD DATA` call might look like:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/to/rb'
INTO TABLE jeremy_table_test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' -- or '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(sha1, @var1, trendx)
SET vsdt = TRIM(TRAILING ')' FROM TRIM(LEADING '(' FROM @var1));
```

To make this call from your Python code, you may try something like this:

```
query = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/to/rb' INTO TABLE jeremy_table_test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (sha1, @var1, trendx) SET vsdt = TRIM(TRAILING ')' FROM TRIM(LEADING '(' FROM @var1))"
cursor.execute(query)
connection.commit()
```

Comment: can you edit it in full code? I can't  understand the formatting of load data infile, just a newbie here

Comment: I don't understand your request.  My answer is about as clear as it can be.  You might want to try running `LOAD DATA` first from the command line, to make sure that there are no issues there.  Then, once you are sure it works, try running it from your Python code.

Comment: tried it but gives me ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IGNORE 1 LINES' at line 1

Comment: great but how can i use load data using variable, my variable is like this: fullPath = mypath + "\\" + theFile using fullPath

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: my variable fullPath has the filename in it, how can i use it in "LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/to/rb'

Comment: Use concatenation?

Comment: atlast I made it

Answer (score 2):

Skip the row when you read it in, rather than when you write it.

```
with open(fullPath, 'rb') as file:
    csv_data = csv.reader(file)
    next(csv_data)
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    for row in csv_data:
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO jeremy_table_test(sha1,vsdt,trendx)'
                'VALUES(%s, %s, %s)',[(row[0]),(row[1]),(row[2]))
    mydb.commit()
    cursor.close()
    print("Done")
```

Comment: thanks, now my only problem is to delete the chars in my second column

Comment: Can u explain why two different cursors are taken? Tough only 1 is used. And in `next(csvreader)` what is csvreader?

Comment: Yeah, to be honest I din't look at that part of the code, just cleaned up the bit OP asked about. There is no need for the lines referring to `mydb.commit()`.

Comment: @Godshand, just use string slicing to remove the unwanted characters if they are only the first and last, and are consistently present. E.g., `row[1][1:]` will drop the first character from your 2nd column value every time. If they are only present on some rows, then you will need something trickier, probably use regex.

Comment: @ Shivam Seth, my bad typing is the reason for the error in next() - fixed now, thanks.